# Python variable value assignment in recursion

Tags: python, variables, recursion, binary-tree, variable-assignment

There are two solution for a problem:

Problem is :

Enter the root node of a binary tree and an integer to print out the path where the sum of the node values in the binary tree is the input integer. A path is defined as a path from the root node of the tree to the next node until the leaf node passes. (Note: In the list of return values, the array with the largest array length is ahead)

solution one

```
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.left = None
#         self.right = None
class Solution:
    def FindPath(self, root, expectNumber):
        if not root:
            return []
        result=[]
        path=[root]
        path_sum=0
        def find(root,path,path_sum):
            isleaf= root.left==None and root.right==None  # a bool,whether is leaf node

            path_sum+=root.val
            if isleaf and path_sum==expectNumber:
                t=[]
                for i in path:
                    t.append(i.val)
                result.append(t) # add a appropriate path's value to result
            if path_sum<expectNumber:
                if root.left:

                    find(root.left,path+[root.left],path_sum)#note!!!!!
                if root.right:

                    find(root.right,path+[root.right],path_sum)#note!!!!!

        find(root,path,path_sum)
        return result
```

solution 2

```
class Solution:
    def FindPath(self, root, expectNumber):
        if not root:
            return []
        result=[]
        path=[]
        path_sum=0
        def find(root,path,path_sum):
            isleaf= root.left==None and root.right==None
            path.append(root)#note!!!!!
            path_sum+=root.val
            if isleaf and path_sum==expectNumber:
                t=[]
                for i in path:
                    t.append(i.val)
                result.append(t)
            if path_sum<expectNumber:
                if root.left:
                    find(root.left,path,path_sum)
                if root.right:
                    find(root.right,path,path_sum)
            path.pop()#note!!!!!
        find(root,path,path_sum)
        return result
```

I don't know why in solution 1 the path list don't need pop operation but solution 2 need. In other word why solution 1 don't share a path list, but solution 2 does.

Please help me, I cann't find such paper figure me out!

My point is not about class , you can use function to solve this problem too.

What I care is Python **variable value assignment in recursion**!!!

Comment: Try tracing through the execution-—in a debugger, or a visualizer like PythonTutor, or by adding `print`s, or just on paper, so you can see what callls are made, and what `path` is at each point. If you can’t do that, no explanation will make sense; if you can do that, you’re 90% of the way to answering it yourself.

Comment: @abarnert I know how to debugger and i have known how the list change in recursion, but point is I don't konw why ,and I want to konw why

Comment: @abarnert ''what calls are made'' means what? can you explain

Answer (score 0):

I find your code has a lot of mistakes that will make it hard to trace:

**** First: any def or function inside any Python class should be lower case with underscores, so we can figure out what is class from a function, so your FindPath() should be >>>>>> find_path()

**** Second: If you wand to declare any arguments to a the global scope of a class, you should do that inside a function as a constructor or initializer, so your code for an E.G should be :

```
class Solution:
    def __init__(self, root, expect_number):
        self.root = root
        self.expect_number = expect_number
```

and any time you will call any argument inside the class, you should call it with the (self.arg), e.g self.root

**** Third: this line is not understandable at all :

```
def find(root,path,path_sum):
            isleaf= root.left==None and root.right==None
```

this is totally wrong you are assigning a None value to preassaigned value to isleaf, and you again give the isleaf variable an (and) word so, as a logical or pythonic logic : how would the isleaf will understand to get the two values (root.left and root.right) which are getting a None values, does not make any sense.
so please give us an idea about what exactly do you want to do here.

**** Fourth: consider to give one space after and before any operator so instead of 
 "if path_sum

**** Don't afraid to give the variables or arguments a real names to discripe the real needs for it, or at least try to give a comment for it, So e.g : what is t = [] is doing!!!!!!!

So please try to be more specific so you can find good help for your problems, and to make your code more pythonic.

---

New Edit:

In solution no 2 : every time you call the find() function, you are appending or adding the 'root' value to the path list

```
    def find(root,path,path_sum):
        isleaf= root.left==None and root.right==None
        path.append(root) # here you added the root to the path
```

and the code still recursive till this condition is false:

```
if path_sum<expectNumber:
```

and when it false, it will start to call the pop() method, which will remove 
the last 'root', added to the path list:

```
path.pop()
```

and then it calls the next line, which will call the find function again

```
find(root,path,path_sum)
```

but this time will call it with empty path value, WHY? 
because the first path list object "path=[]" is at the same level scope as 
the calling of the last find function "find(root,path,path_sum)"
so the inner path argument and it's values not seen by the outer path scope, they only seen by the find() function it self.

And this scope issues exactly the same to "Solution 1", except you are passing a path list with root value, and when this condition is False

```
if path_sum<expectNumber:
```

the code will call the find() function again but with path only having the root value in the first announcement "path=[root]".

And After all I think with respect you are not sharing the whole code for privacy issue, so it's hard to find the answer easily.

Comment: It's a problem form Chinese code web 牛客网    https://www.nowcoder.com/practice/b736e784e3e34731af99065031301bca?tpId=13&tqId=11177&tPage=2&rp=2&ru=/ta/coding-interviews&qru=/ta/coding-interviews/question-ranking

Comment: isleaf= root.left==None and root.right==None
It means a logic result: isleaf is bool

Comment: my question is not about class' variable
What I care is variable value assignment in recursion

Comment: You can image this class as two function

Answer (score -1):

You can simplify your recursive method several ways. First, at each iteration, check if the value of the node passed to the method along with the sum of the current path contents is less than or equal to the desired value. Second, should the latter be smaller, call the method on the left and right sides of the tree:

```
class Solution:
  @classmethod
  def find_path(cls, head, val:int, current = []):
    if sum(current) == val:
       yield current
    elif head.value+sum(current) < val:
      if head.left is not None:
        yield from cls.find_path(head.left, val, current+[head.value])
      if head.right is not None:
        yield from cls.find_path(head.right, val, current+[head.value])
    elif head.value+sum(current) == val:
      yield current+[head.value]
```

---

Tree class for demonstration:

```
class Tree:
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.__dict__ = {i:kwargs.get(i) for i in ['left', 'right', 'value']}

t = Tree(value=10, left=Tree(value=8, left=Tree(value=3), right=Tree(value=5)), right=Tree(value=2, left=Tree(value=2)))

""" 
     10
   /    \
  8      2
 / \    /
3   5  2
"""
results = [list(Solution.find_path(t, i)) for i in [12, 14, 23]]
```

Output:

```
[[[10, 2]], [[10, 2, 2]], [[10, 8, 5]]]
```

Comment: Thanks for anser,but you don't answer my question:"why in solution 1 the path list don't need pop operation but solution 2 need. In other word why solution 1 don't share a path list, but solution 2 does"
By the way , your code is beautiful!